# Authentication for mobile web applications

Tags: security, mobile-website

I am new to mobile web programming - having spent a lot of time designing back end Windows services and some IOS native programming recently.

We are in the process of designing a new app for usage by our end clients. We need it to be light weight, responsive and also work on all mobile devices - IOS, Android and Win 8. After much research we have narrowed down to using HTML 5 based JS framework - namely either Chocolate Chip UI or Phone JS. Server side code is PHP.

I have a question about the best practices for authentication when it comes to mobile Web applications and sites 
We could present the login form with user details and post to server/authenticate and write to an authentication cookie and then redirect to an HTML 5 page from which point on all data GET and POST is using REST Calls.
Or not post to server but authenticate using a service and store an authenticated token or cookie and check when requesting/posting data.

But are the above methods still relevant - since i have never had to deal with UI authentication before - what are the best methodologies when designing  mobile web apps specially with regards to authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Im my JAVA EE projects, I'm using a JDBC Realm for storing users, passwords and roles and JAVA EE build-in Container Managed Security for securing my webpages bases on the roles. If a user is not authenticated a Form will be shown where he or she has to enter the security information. The web pages get data access by services with CRUD functionality. 
For Android, Java FX, WPF and so on I'm using a Restful Interface wrapping the Java specific service to support different programming languages combined with OAuth2 (http://oauth.net/2/). A few benefits of OAuth2 are that no user name and password must be stored on the client side, the obtained token can be refreshed and you could seperate parts of your services by using scopes (read-only, full, only calender access,...) befined by yourself. The tokens must be stored in a database and mapped to the user principal it belongs to if a REST service will be accessed. Your users can be also allowed to register own third-party applications using specific scopes of the REST interface. 
Herr is an example implementation: https://github.com/OpenConextApps/apis/blob/master/README.md and here some information about JAVA EE security: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/security-webtier.htm#BNCAS